# Does tree shaking happens while Dynamically importing named export using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, code-splitting

While doing a dynamic import will tree shaking happen in React JS ?

Eg.

```js
import(/* webpackChunkName: "chunkName" */'../component/Foo').then(module => {
  const {Foo} = module.default
  this.setState({ foo: Foo })
})
```